# Complex matrix layout fails in beamer but ok in MWE

Tags: beamer, matrices

The MWE that follows works fine to layout this complex matrix. But when I paste it into a simple beamer document it fails (I also included that code  Can you help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\begin{document}

\newenvironment{Pbmatrix}[1][c]
 {\begin{adjustbox}{valign=#1}$\begin{pmatrix}}
 {\end{pmatrix}$\end{adjustbox}}

\newcommand{\matt}[5]{
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \begin{Pbmatrix}[b]
  2+r_1 & -1  \\
  -1  & 2+r_1 & -1 \\
      & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
      &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
      &        &        &  -1 & 2+r_1 & -1  \\
      &        &        &   & -1 & 2+r_1  \\    
  \end{Pbmatrix} & #3 \\
  \hfill #4 & #1 & #2\hfill \\ 
  & #5 & \begin{Pbmatrix}[t]
    2+r_2 & -1  \\
    -1  & 2+r_2 & -1 \\
        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
        &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
        &        &        &  -1 & 2+r_2 & -1  \\
        &        &        &   & -1 & 2+r_2  \\    
    \end{Pbmatrix}
  \end{pmatrix}
}

\begin{equation*}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
$\mathbf{A_{if}}=\matt {K_1/h_1+K_2/h_2} {-K_2/h_2} {-1} {-K_1/h_1} {-1}$
}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

This Beamer document doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,adjustbox,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\newenvironment{Pbmatrix}[1][c]
 {\begin{adjustbox}{valign=#1}$\begin{pmatrix}}
 {\end{pmatrix}$\end{adjustbox}}

\newcommand{\matt}[5]{
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \begin{Pbmatrix}[b]
  2+r_1 & -1  \\
  -1  & 2+r_1 & -1 \\
      & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
      &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
      &        &        &  -1 & 2+r_1 & -1  \\
      &        &        &   & -1 & 2+r_1  \\    
  \end{Pbmatrix} & #3 \\
  \hfill #4 & #1 & #2\hfill \\ 
  & #5 & \begin{Pbmatrix}[t]
    2+r_2 & -1  \\
    -1  & 2+r_2 & -1 \\
        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
        &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
        &        &        &  -1 & 2+r_2 & -1  \\
        &        &        &   & -1 & 2+r_2  \\    
    \end{Pbmatrix}
  \end{pmatrix}
}

\begin{equation*}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
$\mathbf{A_{if}}=\matt {K_1/h_1+K_2/h_2} {-K_2/h_2} {-1} {-K_1/h_1} {-1}$
}
\end{equation*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try to define your command and environment out side frame environment

Comment: @touhami It's the correct answer. Commands for general usage should always been defined before `\begin{document}`. With `beamer` there are additional complications due to the fact that the frame contents is absorbed as an argument.

Comment: @BobZigon Just implement egreg's comment and it works fine.  Move both the `newenvironment` and the `newcommand` to just before `\begin{document}` and works fine (albeit a bit tiny on font)

Comment: Your suggestion about moving it outside the frame environment worked. Thanks.

Comment: @touhami Would you add an answer (and ping me when you've done it)?

Comment: @egreg answer add, sorry i was in offline.

Answer (score 1):

Commands and environments should be defined before `\begin{document}` and you can redefine them between frames

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,adjustbox,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\newenvironment{Pbmatrix}[1][c]
 {\begin{adjustbox}{valign=#1}$\begin{pmatrix}}
 {\end{pmatrix}$\end{adjustbox}}
\newcommand{\matt}[5]{
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \begin{Pbmatrix}[b]
  2+r_1 & -1  \\
  -1  & 2+r_1 & -1 \\
      & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
      &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
      &        &        &  -1 & 2+r_1 & -1  \\
      &        &        &   & -1 & 2+r_1  \\    
  \end{Pbmatrix} & #3 \\
  \hfill #4 & #1 & #2\hfill \\ 
  & #5 & \begin{Pbmatrix}[t]
    2+r_2 & -1  \\
    -1  & 2+r_2 & -1 \\
        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
        &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
        &        &        &  -1 & 2+r_2 & -1  \\
        &        &        &   & -1 & 2+r_2  \\    
    \end{Pbmatrix}
  \end{pmatrix}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{equation*}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
$\mathbf{A_{if}}=\matt {K_1/h_1+K_2/h_2} {-K_2/h_2} {-1} {-K_1/h_1} {-1}$
}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

%----------------------- \matt redefined
\renewcommand{\matt}{notning}

\begin{frame}
\matt
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```